# How can I resolve "SAML Providers must reference at least one SAML assertion issuer" message?

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, saml, keycloak

I want to setup a SSO solution using Keycloak 10.0.2 as the Identity Provider. The first application I want to setup is AWS.

I followed [this](https://scandiweb.com/blog/sign-in-to-amazon-aws-using-saml-protocol-and-keycloak-as-identity-provider) tutorial to enable Keycloak to sign me in using SAML. I noticed, that this tutorial is guiding me to download the “SAML Metadata IDPSSODescriptor” from the client's "Installation"-Tab. However, I can only choose "SAML Metadata SPSSODescriptor".

In AWS, I entered the name of my realm as "Provider Name" and imported the SPSSODescriptor. This led to the following error: `SAML Providers must reference at least one SAML assertion issuer.`

Answer (score 3):

In downloaded xml file change SPSSODescriptor to IDPSSODescriptor for both opening and closing tags. Also entityID should be "https://KEYCLOAK-URL/auth/realms/YOUR-REALMS-NAME"

Answer (score 0):

Use the command:

```
wget https://KEYCLOAK-URL/auth/realms/YOUR-REALMS-NAME/protocol/saml/descriptor
```

and

```
upload descripter
```